# WikiJS и Pterodactyl Вместе

Tags: ubuntu

Хочу спросить, можно ли установить WikiJS и Pterodactyl вместе на одной VPS?
Как бы порты 80 и 443 заняты WikiJS, а Pterodactyl требует их.. И вот пока смотрю гайд по быстрой установке Pterodactyl уже сомневаюсь что эту панель можно установить.

(Я с этим Pterodactyl и WikiJS почти всё лето профукал и всё забыл, так что освежаю память)